# How to do constructor injection if i have primitive data types in the class

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to do constructor injection.I am trying to inject another object but it shows me error saying that it expects Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.Student required a bean of type 'int' that could not be found.
When i try to do constructor injection without having prmitive data type it works.
I am attaching the code for reference

```
    package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        Student student=context.getBean(Student.class);
//      student.show();
//      student.getLaptop().show();
        

    }

}


package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class Student {
    
    private int sid;
    private String sname;
    
    
    private Laptop laptop;
    public int getSid() {
        return sid;
    }
    public void setSid(int sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }
    public String getSname() {
        return sname;
    }
    public void setSname(String sname) {
        this.sname = sname;
    }
    public Laptop getLaptop() {
        return laptop;
    }
    
    
    public Student() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    @Autowired

    public Student(int sid, String sname, Laptop laptop) {
        super();
        this.sid = sid;
        this.sname = sname;
        this.laptop = laptop;
                
    }
    public void setLaptop(Laptop laptop) {
        this.laptop = laptop;
        
    }
    
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("I am student class which which is being called through bean instantiation");
    }

}

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Laptop {
    
    private int lid;
    private String lname;
    public int getLid() {
        return lid;
    }
    public void setLid(int lid) {
        this.lid = lid;
    }
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("I am laptop class which is being shown");
    }

}
```

Comment: Change those ints into Integers.  Where will the injected values come from?  Perhaps they're generated by JPA.  That will work.

Comment: @duffymo its still giving error ((Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.Student required a bean of type 'java.lang.Integer' that could not be found.)).

Comment: Ask yourself "where will this bean come from?"  If Spring isn't generating it, you cannot inject it.  It's per-instance in this case.  I don't think Laptop and Student should be Spring beans.  Everything in an application need not be under Spring's control.

Comment: @duffymo thanks i got it:))